# QPrinter: fit the html table into a4 sheet (in pdf format)

Tags: html, c++, qt, pdf

I could not find an answer to this problem - My QT application generates a html output which has tables and figures (the size of the table-rows and columns- is not known beforehand).

I have to create a pdf exporter from this html file. I used the [QPrinter](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprinter.html) class provided by Qt to do this. The problem I am facing is, when I have very long tables (many columns), I am not able to print the pdf document properly.

Ideally, I want the pdf to contain the table with one below the other

```
--------------------------------------
alpha | beta | gamma | delta | epsilon
one 
two 
three
--------------------------------------
```

If the above table exceeds the A4 sheet size, I want it to be printed as

```
--------------------
alpha | beta | gamma 
one 
two 
three
--------------------
---------------
delta | epsilon
one
two 
three
---------------
```

Currently, when I try to print it, the part of the table that exceeds the A4 size disappears. For printing, I load the contents of html file onto QString object. Then I use the following,

```
QWebView document;
document.setHtml(qStr); //qStr is QString object

QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
printer.setOutputFileName("output.pdf");
document.print(&printer);
```

The html file is very simple- it contains only the table element. I have put the html file in this plunker - [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/g9f68REYVnREqkUX39Nc?p=preview)

How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance. 
(I am required to use to the QPrinter functionality)

Comment: You have not included any code that actually prints. You only show how you set your deprecated webkit instance (the web view), and the printer. But you don't show any actual printing. Since you use (old) webkit, make sure that webkit itself implements the functionality you need. You will need special html/css to support a table that wraps around; it might not be trivial and you need to read up on it. A table by default won't wrap horizontally - just look in any browser, they don't do it.

Comment: This question is off topic without a complete html sample that will correctly wrap on printing in major browsers. E.g. show something that prints wrapped from Firefox and Chrome. If you want to ask how to implement it in html, that'd be a separate question.

Comment: @KubaOber, this is the code that prints the html file into pdf in my qt application, I have updated with the html sample now. I am using the QPrinter class given by Qt.

Comment: Does your html print properly when you try printing from Firefox or Chrome? If it doesn't, then the problem is with your html/css and you have to fix it first, perhaps ask a separate question about how to fix it but you'll have to minimize your html/css first, too. Remove all unnecessary styling. Leave only enough html/css to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: "I am using the QPrinter class given by Qt." Sure you are, but that's not very relevant. What you're really using is the webkit rendering engine to lay out your document. Your document must be designed to wrap the table around when printed. It won't happen automagically. You must design it to act that way in the context of a paper page. You should get it printing correctly in standard browsers first, it'll then likely print just fine from webkit bundled with Qt. Again, the problem is with html/css, and you can use any browser to debug/fix that issue (you must!).

Comment: @KubaOber, thanks - Yes, I see the problem now, its not printing properly in chrome (and firefox) - so it's an issue of designing the html/css. I'll close this question.